# Breezejs saving entities inheritance issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, breeze

I am using breezejs and membershipreboot for my SPA and I'm trying to override the beforesaveentitiesdelegate for adding a new customer.

I have a customer class that inherits from the membershipreboot 'RelationalUserAccount' as follows:

```
public class Customer : RelationalUserAccount
{
    public virtual string FirstName { get; private set; }
    public virtual string LastName { get; private set; }
}
```

and I use the following code for the 'BeforeSaveEntitiesDelegate' :

```
public Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> AddCustomer(Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> saveMap)
        {
                Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>> newSaveMap = new Dictionary<Type, List<EntityInfo>>();

                var type = saveMap.FirstOrDefault();

                if (type.Key == typeof(Customer))
                {
                    EntityInfo entityInfo = type.Value.First();

                    List<EntityInfo> customers = new List<EntityInfo>();

                    if (entityInfo.EntityState == EntityState.Added)
                    {
                        Customer customertoCreate = entityInfo.Entity as Customer;}

                        newSaveMap.Add(typeof(Customer), customers);
                    }
                }
            }
            return newSaveMap;
        }
```

when I break into the code, only the firstname and lastname fields are populated, none of the other inherited fields contain any data, the base type for the 'customer' entity appears to be 'customer' - shouldn't this be RelationalUserAccount?[image: base type is wrong]

The strange thing is though in the following code, savebundle seems to have the correct data in:

```
    public SaveResult CustomerAdd(JObject saveBundle)
    {
        CustomerBusinessLogic customerLogic = new CustomerBusinessLogic(mContextProvider);
        mContextProvider.BeforeSaveEntitiesDelegate = customerLogic.AddCustomer;
        return mContextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
    }
```

Here's the dump from the saveBundle, as you can see the username and email fields are populated:

```
  "entities": [
    {
      "Key": -1,
      "FirstName": "asdf",
      "LastName": "asdf",
      "IsEmailVerified": false,
      "ID": "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
      "Tenant": "3",
      "Username": "asdf@asdf.com",
      "Created": "1900-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "LastUpdated": "1900-01-01T00:00:00Z",
      "IsAccountClosed": false,
      "AccountClosed": null,
      "IsLoginAllowed": false,
      "LastLogin": null,
      "LastFailedLogin": null,
      "FailedLoginCount": 0,
      "PasswordChanged": null,
      "RequiresPasswordReset": false,
      "Email": "asdf@asdf.com",
      "IsAccountVerified": false,
      "LastFailedPasswordReset": null,
      "FailedPasswordResetCount": 0,
      "MobileCode": null,
      "MobileCodeSent": null,
      "MobilePhoneNumber": null,
      "MobilePhoneNumberChanged": null,
      "AccountTwoFactorAuthMode": "0",
      "CurrentTwoFactorAuthStatus": "0",
      "VerificationKey": null,
      "VerificationPurpose": null,
      "VerificationKeySent": null,
      "VerificationStorage": null,
      "HashedPassword": null,
      "entityAspect": {
        "entityTypeName": "Customer:#Application.Domain.CustomerAggregate",
        "defaultResourceName": "Customers",
        "entityState": "Added",
        "originalValuesMap": {},
        "autoGeneratedKey": {
          "propertyName": "Key",
          "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "saveOptions": {}
}
```

Comment: Are you saying that you see the complete data in the `SaveBundle` but not in the first `entityInfo.Entity`? That would be strange.

Comment: Yeah, but in the saveBundle it doesn't seem to know that it is an inherited type. The only thing I can really think of is that 'RelationalUserAccount' isn't an abstract class, but it also isn't declared as a dbset in the dbcontext. It therefore also doesn't appear in the breeze/metadata endpoint. Could this be the case?

Comment: I downloaded the latest source for Breeze.ContextProvider it looks like its the following line in which newtonsoft doesn't seem to convert the object properly entityInfo.Entity = JsonSerializer.Deserialize(new JTokenReader(jo), entityType); line 231 in ContextProvider.cs